# What is the definition of the term "substitution" in the Scala Language Specification?

Tags: scala, types

In the Scala Language Specs (version 2.9 - June 11, 2014), in the section about existential types the term "substitution" is used, however, the meaning of substitution does not seem to be defined in the Scala Language Specification.

Could someone explain what substitution means in this context ?

Does it mean that a type variable in a type expression is substituted with an other concrete type or type variable or type constructor ?

If the substitution is meant to be a concrete type, then what is concrete types are considered? The ones which are in scope as a simple name ?

What would be a meaningful definition for the concept "substitution" in this context ?

What is being substituted with what ?

[image]

Comment: Just guessing, but perhaps it refers to the [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)

Answer (score 2):

It refers to the substitution concept of lambda-calculus. From a practical point of view, it is a replacement of free variables with bounded ones. For a more formal definition, you can look at the theory of lambda calculus.

Comment: Thank you for the valuable insight. I mostly read Pierce's book on types, so I have a basic understanding  on λ calculus. Which is not clear to me is what does variable mean in this case ? What can be a variable? Any type? Any type constructor ? Concrete types? Higher kinded types?

Comment: I don't quite understand what do you mean by saying : replacing free variables with bounded ones? As far as I know substitution occurs in λ calculus when applying a term to another term, i.e. X Y.  In that case a formal parameter in X (a bound variable) is replaced by the actual parameter Y which itself might contain free variables. I don't think that free variables are replaced with anything during application (which is carried out by substitution).